# Creating a Regex That Applies to multiple lengths of strings and characters

Tags: python, regex

```
PLAY [[B2 C3# D3 D3# ]]
PLAY [[A1 A1# B1 D1# E1 F1 F1# G1 A2 B2 F2# G2 C3 C3# D3 D3# ]]
```

I need to create a regex (with the ultimate purpose of removing "PLAY" and "[[]]" from all lines of a text file. The insides of the brackets will vary with each line, so how do I create a regex match pattern to return only the group within the brackets for each line?

Any help is appreciated, I'm kind of a noob with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you know the start and end strings and their lengths, just slice the part you need:

```
>>> s = "PLAY [[A1 A1# B1 D1# E1 F1 F1# G1 A2 B2 F2# G2 C3 C3# D3 D3# ]]"
>>> s[7:-3]
'A1 A1# B1 D1# E1 F1 F1# G1 A2 B2 F2# G2 C3 C3# D3 D3#'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.sub`

```
for line in file_obj:
    print re.sub(r'.*\bPLAY\s*\[\[(.*?)\]\].*', r'\1', line)
```

Comment: Given the input format seems static, `re` seems to be a little overkill here.

Comment: op wants to use regex... THat's why I came here.. If op chooses the other one then i'll delete mine..

Comment: [OP wants to use regex, does he?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Yeah, I need to use regex, but both answers work (:thanks!

Comment: You _need_ to use regex? Is it for an assignment on the topic of regex?